# How do I apply RStudio themes only to the source and console backgrounds and not to the whole GUI?

Tags: r, user-interface, rstudio

I'm using RStudio 1.1.383 and R 3.4.3 and I'm trying to apply a theme under Options > Appearance only to the background text area of the source pane and the console pane. This is exactly what happens when I apply a theme on my desktop computer (Win10), but when I apply a theme on my laptop (also Win10), it applies the theme to the entire GUI except for the top menu bar (i.e. File, Edit, Code, etc). The result looks jarring. Why might themes be behaving differently between my two computers which use identical setups? Is there an option that I might have selected somewhere on one and not the other that would cause the theme to apply to just the text area of a couple panes in one case and the entire GUI in the other?

Comment: Under Options / Appearance, set "Editor Theme" to set the text area colors, and "RStudio Theme" to set the menubar/window theme.

Comment: Ah, well, not exactly, but thank you for setting me in a direction that helped answer my question. It seems that selecting the Classic RStudio theme sets different colors to the GUI itself so that you can independently set the Editor theme without affecting the GUI. If you select Modern for the RStudio theme, the GUI changes to dark or light colors based on the Editor theme you choose. I was trying to use a dark Editor theme without making the entire GUI dark.

Comment: Curious, I've never noticed, as I've never used a light theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is a change in RStudio v1.1 -- now, when a 'dark' editor theme is selected, the entire IDE will be themed to match that.

If you'd prefer to have a dark editor theme with a light IDE theme, that's unfortunately not possible in v1.1. You might want to file a feature request at https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues.